# Synchronizing Favorites between Microsoft Edge

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I'm using Microsoft Edge on my fresh upgraded Windows 10. I imported my Chrome Bookmarks to Edge and just wanted to see if there is any way to sync my bookmarks across all my PC's?

I'm using a Microsoft Account for my sign in. Is there a way to sync them to onedrive for example and resync them on all my other machines?

Answer (score 2):

For current stable edition it is not available. But for insider program build(10586) it is possible to sync browser data using Microsoft account. This build will be available as stable release as Threshold 2 in few days.

Update:
Windows 10 Threshold 2 available now. Edge data can be synced using Microsoft account.

Answer (score 0):

That should be possible!

> This isn’t something new, Mozilla offers the same in Firefox Sync, and so does Google with Chrome Sync. All you need to do is install the browser and sign in to your Sync account, and it will synchronize your selected preferences and data from the server to your device. Besides its usefulness for browsing on multiple Windows devices you own, it will be incredibly useful when setting up a new device.

**Source:** [Microsoft Edge will support syncing of password, bookmarks, tabs and history](http://www.filecritic.com/microsoft-edge-will-support-syncing-of-password-bookmarks-tabs-and-history/#ixzz3hk1NSC4J)

Comment: Well in fact this means: Yes it will be possible, but No currently this isn't possible. Right? Is there a way for a workaround? Anything mentioned for this? As it would be really beneficial for the start.

Comment: In Edge not really, I think. I'm keeping firefox because of this.

Comment: Well In this case I had to stay at Chrome until this feature is implemented.

Comment: @Ionic - You can store your sync your Edge favorites to OneDrive yourself, using a folder sync program, but until Edge supports extension another solution will be tough.

Comment: Yes this can be a solution too. Maybe using a short powershell which monitors the folder and sync it to a onedrive folder. Maybe I'll take a look at it later.